# Watch variable changes in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a way to watch variable changes in Jquery/Javascript like it is the case in AngularJS ?

Comment: Yes - use the console

Comment: Pres F12 > Console

Comment: This is far too vague and broad. Give us a code example of exactly what you want to do. For instance, ES2015's `Proxy` might be what you're looking for, or ES5's getters/setters, but in both cases they relate to objects and their properties, not variables.

Comment: Try using '.text()' method of Jquery to update an element of the HTML anytime you changes your variable. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That is a great question !!! And a very useful one.

Comment: @O_Z you're welcome!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You locked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses a digest cycle to detect changes after you update a variable. For instance, when you click on an element, it will change variables in scopes, and will immediately trigger a look through to see what has changed. You can accomplish something similar using a simple interval function:

```
var _watch = null;
var test = null;
setInterval(function() {
    if ( _watch !== test ) {
        _watch = test;
        console.log('Variable changed.', test);
    }
}, 100);
```

To test this out, simply type `test = "test"` in the console, and you should see "Variable changed."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `obj.watch` but it's only supported in Gecko (Basically firefox) for now.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Edit: For Chrome , `Object.observe` can be used.

Comment: "for now" - It will never be in the standard, we have `Proxy` for that now. Also, it's for objects, not variables.

Answer (score -1):

Use a getter/setter method:

```
var log = ['test'];
var obj = {
  get latest () {
    if (log.length == 0) return undefined;
    console.log('getting latest!'); // or trigger an event
    return log[log.length - 1]
  }
}
console.log (obj.latest); // Will return "test".
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get