# How to get before and after value on global variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, onchange

I have a global variable like `let currentPhoto = 0;`

The value gets changed around by various functions. I need a function which watches this variable and when it gets changed it gives me back two numbers.

The first is what it got changed from, and the second is what it got changed to.

Is this possible in jQuery?

Some asked for the context.

My code is the following: [My code on codepen](https://codepen.io/-X-Peter-X-/pen/BaRMXVo)

Now I need to change classes on the thumbnails for the active image in the bigPic.

My logic was, to change the first thumbnails class in document.ready. Remove the 'box' and add the 'active' class with addClass and removeClass

After that I would watch currentPhoto and when it gets changed I would remove 'active' and add 'box' class from the  thumbnail index equal to currentPhoto from what it got changed from, and do the oposite to the one that it got changed to.

Comment: _"jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like **HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler** with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers."_ - That's not a jQuery topic.

Comment: This sounds like another [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What's the actual use case that would make such a "global variable observer" necessary?

Comment: If you need this behaviour there are much better suited methods than a global variable. I'd suggest creating a new class which you call methods of to update. This way you can store the value in a property to easily retrieve its previous/current state, and return that to the caller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Watch variable changes in Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396558/watch-variable-changes-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Your solution is:  don't change images with `variable++`.  Instead of `currentPhoto++` call `nextPhoto()` and handle currentPhoto++ inside that function along with anything else that needs to be done, including range check and loadPhoto.

Comment: I can and need to change photos from the thumbnails as well, so, I'm able to chang to any of them.

Comment: Ok, not `nextPhoto()` instead, `loadPhoto(newIndex)` then you can do nextbutton->loadPhoto(--currentPhoto) and thumb->loadPhoto(thumbIndex).   Here ya go:  https://jsfiddle.net/u86btewx/1/ (edit: added border to thumb / `.length-1` already handled)

Comment: You don't even need to know the currentPhoto as you can remove the `active` from the box with `$(".box.active").removeClass("active")` without needing to reference its index/id/etc.